# Regex for "Starts with" pattern including +1 line when match is equal to given word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

"Regex" Perl 5 compatible

I am looking for regex for "Starts with" pattern type.

"Starts with": obtain sentence from starting with the word given till it find delimited character "@@"(forward direction). If match found is "Start word itself",then it should read from +1 line within two delimiter'@@'.

e.g.
@@bank representative does not permit the purchase of traveler's checks, bank drafts, certain wire transfers, or the completion of certain credit applications like mortgages.These transactions still need to take place face-to-face with a executive.@@Convenience is a major advantage of online banking. Basic banking transactions such as paying bills and transferring funds between accounts can easily be done 24 hours a day, seven days a week, wherever a consumer wishes.@@bank representative@@Other functions may include ordering checks@@

Find: Starts with "bank representative"

Match 1: Online banking does not permit the purchase of traveler's checks, bank drafts, certain wire transfers, or the completion of certain credit applications like mortgages.These transactions still need to take place face-to-face with a bank representative.

Match 2: Other functions may include ordering checks

I was able to get "Starts With" pattern matching string, but i got stuck with getting new line when expression matches the given word.

https://regex101.com/r/ZzGEoj/1

@@\s*+bank representative\b.*?(?=@@)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(?<=@@)bank representative[\s\w\.',-]*(?=@@)
```

**Explained:**

- `(?<=@@)` starts with @@ (positive lookbehind).
- … then your string …
- `[\s\w\.',-]*` followed with a zero or more occurrences of whitespace or any word or punctuation symbols.
- `(?=@@)`  ends with @@ (positive lookahead).

Comment: Hi,thanks for trying it out. However,  I am able to get Match 1 of the result but not match 2. I think for match 2, i have to try using some python script as well. Not sure if it's possible via regex only.